# ERROR: file.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, debian-buster

I am trying to create my own docker image containing [`tensorflow`](https://www.tensorflow.org/). My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7.9-buster as python-base

RUN apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

FROM python-base as venv-image

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential g++ tk python-tk python3-tk tk-dev

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install notebook pandas numpy seaborn

ENV TF_WHEEL_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
RUN pip install --upgrade $TF_WHEEL_URL

FROM python-base AS app-image

COPY --from=venv-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN chown -R nobody /usr/src/app/
RUN usermod --home /tmp nobody

USER nobody

ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/src/app
```

When I try to build the image I get the following error:

```
$ jbezdek@mac> docker build -t my-image:latest .
[+] Building 65.1s (10/14)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.15kB                                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7.9-buster                                                                                                                                                           1.3s
 => [python-base 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7.9-buster@sha256:83ab4e9e275cb279e5639097aa0780ef82c4fd78622ae36ab35810ab7b57f491                                                                                        28.5s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.7.9-buster@sha256:83ab4e9e275cb279e5639097aa0780ef82c4fd78622ae36ab35810ab7b57f491                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:9e9cd01e30157128ef9b104c9584cde69df1374be10ece82568c94e5b0d6af19 2.22kB / 2.22kB                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => sha256:06af62193c25241eb123af8cf115c7a6298e834976fe148ac79ec11a7ca06ee5 7.69MB / 7.69MB                                                                                                                                   2.2s
 => => sha256:8b846e1b73901174c506ae5e6219ac2f356ef71eaa5896dfbc238dc67ca4bf73 9.98MB / 9.98MB                                                                                                                                   1.4s
 => => sha256:83ab4e9e275cb279e5639097aa0780ef82c4fd78622ae36ab35810ab7b57f491 1.86kB / 1.86kB                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => sha256:42bec75914596fe7d61bfda973083109baddab48b6a591c713874c9c66e0978d 9.02kB / 9.02kB                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => sha256:c78c297fb0d010ee085f95ae439636ecb167b050c1acb4273bd576998cf94a83 49.18MB / 49.18MB                                                                                                                                12.7s
 => => sha256:fb44d26a138a8d064a4ab8f9b472c64e7136c2482ec5af19bab8811b6d2c15b7 52.17MB / 52.17MB                                                                                                                                13.5s
 => => sha256:195488cfc78f0e257698fa052494b5340338b5acfdec4df1b249942044222274 183.89MB / 183.89MB                                                                                                                              22.9s
 => => extracting sha256:c78c297fb0d010ee085f95ae439636ecb167b050c1acb4273bd576998cf94a83                                                                                                                                        1.5s
 => => sha256:e91064730500746be97b6f35ae9c33bf1d9b7b0b4e9fd5f766c84ff08d25502b 6.26MB / 6.26MB                                                                                                                                  14.4s
 => => sha256:0a78fc05d06f8aba012b30a2db688a3e2e703e317d2ec7e40be76204c670b0a1 15.95MB / 15.95MB                                                                                                                                17.0s
 => => sha256:521c43ca96ec8c9641af8aed110859966134fffa21e63748fec100576e252e14 232B / 232B                                                                                                                                      14.8s
 => => extracting sha256:06af62193c25241eb123af8cf115c7a6298e834976fe148ac79ec11a7ca06ee5                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => extracting sha256:8b846e1b73901174c506ae5e6219ac2f356ef71eaa5896dfbc238dc67ca4bf73                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => sha256:7dafbffb30bdcb6256e239d9b43c57b9522dd79c39d078ce5f0e1b98dc210c2a 2.16MB / 2.16MB                                                                                                                                  15.7s
 => => extracting sha256:fb44d26a138a8d064a4ab8f9b472c64e7136c2482ec5af19bab8811b6d2c15b7                                                                                                                                        1.7s
 => => extracting sha256:195488cfc78f0e257698fa052494b5340338b5acfdec4df1b249942044222274                                                                                                                                        4.3s
 => => extracting sha256:e91064730500746be97b6f35ae9c33bf1d9b7b0b4e9fd5f766c84ff08d25502b                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => extracting sha256:0a78fc05d06f8aba012b30a2db688a3e2e703e317d2ec7e40be76204c670b0a1                                                                                                                                        0.4s
 => => extracting sha256:521c43ca96ec8c9641af8aed110859966134fffa21e63748fec100576e252e14                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:7dafbffb30bdcb6256e239d9b43c57b9522dd79c39d078ce5f0e1b98dc210c2a                                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => [python-base 2/2] RUN apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev                                                                                                                           3.2s
 => [venv-image 1/5] RUN apt-get install -y build-essential g++ tk python-tk python3-tk tk-dev                                                                                                                                   1.2s
 => [venv-image 2/5] RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv                                                                                                                                                                               1.6s
 => [venv-image 3/5] RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                                                                    1.5s
 => [venv-image 4/5] RUN pip install notebook pandas numpy seaborn                                                                                                                                                              27.1s
 => ERROR [venv-image 5/5] RUN pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl                                                                0.4s
------
 > [venv-image 5/5] RUN pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl:
#10 0.399 ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade $TF_WHEEL_URL]: exit code: 1
```

Honestly, I really don't get it. It says that `tensorflow_cpu-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`, but I am using Linux platform (buster is Debian) with Python 3.7 on it, and I am installing the package from an [official tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location).

So, what is a problem? What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

This issue is present only on my MacBook Pro (M1, 2020) with MacOS BigSur. When I run the code on MacBook Pro (Intel Core i5, Early 2015) with MacOS Catalina, everything works as expected.

Comment: I remember having issues with manylinux packages due to outdated setuptools. 
As a sanity check, can you update setuptools, too? `RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Comment: @Marat, thank you for your advice. However, I have tried that, and the error is still the same :/

Comment: This is not an answer, but I just tried building exactly the same Dockerfile as one above and it did work.

Comment: re (now missing) question about what system I am building on: I was building this on `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` VM

Answer (score 2):

The following Dockerfile works for me. Changes against the original one are marked with comment.

```
FROM python:3.7.9-buster as python-base

RUN apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

FROM python-base as venv-image

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential g++ tk python-tk python3-tk tk-dev python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install notebook pandas numpy seaborn

ENV TF_WHEEL_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
RUN pip install --upgrade $TF_WHEEL_URL

FROM python-base AS app-image

COPY --from=venv-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN chown -R nobody /usr/src/app/
RUN usermod --home /tmp nobody

USER nobody

ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/src/app
```

I followed the [tensorflow installation manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#1.-install-the-python-development-environment-on-your-system).